# Как исправить ошибку с более чем 3 кавычками при сохранении в базу

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite3

При сохранении данных в базу у меня возникает ошибка:

```
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

Данные, которые пытаюсь сохранить:

```
Остров гоага '''
1000 символов и одна святая ложка ''""
```

Полностью:

```
products_dict = {('category', 'key:15', 'title:PYTHON'): {'#677': {'title': 'Остров гоага '''', 'description': '1000 символов и одна святая ложка ''""', 'price': '19'}}}
```

Мой sql-запрос для сохранения (sqlite3):

```
sql.execute(f'''UPDATE products SET products = "{products_dict}"''')

save.commit()
```

Какие есть способы решения этой проблемы с сохранением и извлечением?

Для чего это нужно? - я должен иметь возможность сохранять любой текст в базу, с разными кавычками и разным количеством кавычек.

Comment: эскейпить или использовать orm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897020/a-good-way-to-escape-quotes-in-a-database-query-string

Comment: Не ясно при чем здесь пользователь. Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас строка это просто строковый литерал в программе, т.е. данные не вводит пользователь, а они жестко прошиты в программе. Поэтому вопрос непонятен. При правильном использовании API для работы с БД, а именно использование связанных переменных, не имеет значения, какие именно данные вы сохраняете. Добавьте в вопрос код, который вы используете для сохранения в БД.

Comment: @Roman Konoval обновил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странный словарь и странное использование базы данных :)

Странный словарь потому что выглядит очень подозрительно строка `'title': 'Остров гоага ''''`, почему тройные одинарные кавычки закрывают только справа, а слева их нет? Т.е., у вас просто синтаксически неправильный код, наверняка, в этом месте ошибка скрипта

**Исправил словарь**, чтобы не было проблем:

```
products_dict = {
    ('category', 'key:15', 'title:PYTHON'): {
        '#677': {
            'title': 'Остров гоага',
            'description': '1000 символов и одна святая ложка',
            'price': '19'
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD.** Варианты исправления синтаксиса с сохранением кавычек в строках:

```
products_dict = {('category', 'key:15', 'title:PYTHON'): {'#677': {'title': 'Остров гоага \'\'\'', 'description': '1000 символов и одна святая ложка ''""', 'price': '19'}}}

products_dict = {('category', 'key:15', 'title:PYTHON'): {'#677': {'title': "Остров гоага '''", 'description': '1000 символов и одна святая ложка ''""', 'price': '19'}}}

products_dict = {('category', 'key:15', 'title:PYTHON'): {'#677': {'title': """Остров гоага '''""", 'description': '1000 символов и одна святая ложка ''""', 'price': '19'}}}
```

---

**Насчет базы данных...** Первое, что бросается в глаза - вы словарь помещаете в запрос как есть, а синтаксис словаря не поддерживается SQL, поэтому будет такая ошибка:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "products": syntax error
```

И **не нужно** вручную формировать запрос с параметрами, нужно использовать биндинга, вот так:

```
sql.execute('UPDATE products SET products=?', [products_dict])
```

Но это полбеды, т.к. `sqlite3` не поддерживает тип словаря, будет такая ошибка:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Можно попробовать сохранить словарь в строку, например через JSON, но и тут будет фигня, т.к. у вас словарь специфичный, его ключ составной, поэтому при сохранении в JSON будет ошибка, т.к. в ключах словаря лучше использовать простые типы:

```
TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not tuple
```

**Это можно обойти, но это будет костылями**. Получить строковое представление словаря через `str(products_dict)`, но возникнет проблем парсинга, если понадобится получить обратно, придется парсить чем-то вроде `ast.literal_eval` из модуля `ast`:

```
sql.execute('UPDATE products SET products=?', [str(products_dict)])
```

---

Думаю, **правильным решением** будет создание нескольких таблиц в базе и заполнения их от этого словаря.

Например, таблицы:

- `Product` (поля id, title, description, price). От вашего словаря это будут значения: `id=677, title='Остров гоага', description='1000 символов и одна святая ложка', price=19`
- `Category` (поля key, title). Значения: `key=15 и title=PYTHON`

Если у одного продукта одна категория, то можно в `Product` хранить категорию в `category_id`, если категорий несколько, то создать связанную таблицу `Product2Category` с полями `product_id` и `category_id`

Comment: изменив словарь - проблема решается, без изменения словаря проблема не решается и ваш ответ тогда не может решить мою текущую проблему: `я должен иметь возможность сохранять любой текст в базу, с разными кавычками и разным количеством кавычек`, я решил пойти дальше и начал кодировать кавычки в собственную кодировку для какой-либо строки, чтобы при извлечении данных иметь возможность получить к примеру, с ключа `description` любые кавычки, написав изменение на какой-либо текст в строке, пример `5393410439ONE` - говорит о том что это одинарная кавычка, позже `str.replace('5393410439ONE', "'")`

Comment: p.s словарь я сохранял как строку в базу, позже через `literal_eval(dict)` получал сам словарь

Comment: @MaximChyorny, у вас словарь в коде имеет неправильный синтаксис, т.к. в коде его неправильно создается. Сама проблема сохранения строк с кавычками не будет возникать - просто используйте биндинг и помещайте как строку. Драйвер базы данных параметры, переданные в биндинге, сам экранирует

Comment: @MaximChyorny, добавил в `UPD` варианты словарей с кавычками. Мои рекомендации: если у вас в строке одинарные кавычки, то используйте двойные для обозначения строки. Если у вас в строке двойные кавычки, то используйте одинарные кавычки для обозначения строки. Исключением будет использование экранирования кавычек через слеш \. Исключением для предыдущих случаев и, возможность совмещать разные кавычки одновременно без экранирования, - использование тройных кавычек

Answer (score 0):

У вас тут комбинация двух проблем

1. неправильное задание строковых литералов
2. использование подстановок параметров в строку в sql запросе

Что касается строковых литералов, то для того чтобы задавать абсолюно произвольный стороковый литерал пользуйтесь простым правилом: экранируйте все символы того типа кавычек, который используете для обозначения начала и конца литерала. Вот примеры строк и то как их нужно задавать в виде строкового литерала в коде (я тут использую одинарную кавычку, но то же самое применимо и к двойным):

```
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
 Строка                                  | Литерал                             
-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
 abc                                     | 'abc'                                  
 Остров гоага '''                        | 'Остров гоага \'\'\''                
 1000 символов и одна святая ложка ''""  | '1000 символов и одна святая ложка \'\'""'
```

Простой способ увидеть этот литерал это заставить питон конвертировать строку с помощью `input()` (способ годится если нет переводов строки). То есть исполнить в терминале:

```
>>> x=input()
```

Потом ввести или вставить текст:

```
1000 символов и одна святая ложка ''""
```

В переменной х теперь строка и если вывести ее представление, то она будет в экранированном виде (в таком какой нужно использовать для задания литерала):

```
>>> print(repr(x))
'1000 символов и одна святая ложка \'\'""'
```

Для сохранения в БД dict-а, как строки, нужно его сначала сериализовать. Можно делать по разному. Простой споcоб это использовать `str`:

```
products_dict_str = str(products_dict)
```

При загрузке из БД нужно будет строку десериализовать с помощью `literal_eval`:

```
products_dict = ast.literal_eval(products_dict_str)
```

Во-вторых, нужно использовать связываемые переменные, а не манипуляции со строками:

```
sql.execute('UPDATE products SET products=?', [products_dict_str])
```

Comment: `json.dumps` не сработает, т.к. ключ составной, я писал об этом :)

Comment: ок, это я пропустил, т.к. главные проблемы не в этом. Сам способ сериализации не имеет принципиального значения, лишь бы он позволял данные хранить.